# VB Clear text file before writing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, text, save

On the click of a button I want to write my textbox.text into a text file.
I got this code working, but I want to clear the textfile before writing and not just add text.

```
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem. _
    OpenTextFileWriter(mfileName, True)
    file.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
    file.Close()
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(mfileName, False)
```

Where `False` disables appending and activates overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [File.WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx)

As explained by MSDN

> Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the
>   file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

Your code becomes just one line

```
File.WriteAllText(mfileName, TextBox1.Text)
```